# Selección filtrada de 2 tablas

Tags: mysql

Como puedo hacer una selección filtrada de dos tablas.
Ejemplo, si tengo el valor de software en las dos tablas como hago para seleccionar lo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el INNER JOIN para relacionar las dos tablas con el mismo campo, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT alumnos.carrera, carreras.carrera FROM ALUMNOS INNER JOIN CARRERAS ON alumnos.carrera = carreras.carrera;
```

Cabe mencionar que el tipo de campo que estas relacionando deben de ser idénticos, o sea `INT` con `INT`, `VARCHAR` con `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Al insertar: SELECT CARRERA FROM ALUMNOS INNER JOIN CARRERAS WHERE ALUMNOS.CARRERA=CARRERAS.CARRERA        Dice que la columna es ambigua

Comment: @JorgeGuadalupeGomezPimentel ya te edite la respuesta.-